# How do I convert a Drush make commit-level dependency into Composer?

Tags: drush, composer

I am remaking old project to use composer for building and I have a problem I cannot find solution to. Basically this is how library is defined in `profile.make` file:

```
; HybridAuth
libraries[hybridauth][directory_name] = 'hybridauth'
libraries[hybridauth][type] = 'library'
libraries[hybridauth][download][type] = 'git'
libraries[hybridauth][download][url] = 'https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth.git'
libraries[hybridauth][download][revision] = 'd4e5bc34008e8c187c302eb4e94200ee4a208c63'
```

How should I rewrite it correctly in my composer.json file? To be precise, how to get revision? This is what I have so far:

```
{
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "library/hybridauth",
        "version": "d4e5bc34008e8c187c302eb4e94200ee4a208c63",
        "type": "drupal-library",
        "dist": {
          "url": "https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth.git",
          "type": "git"
        }
      }
    },
```

it is complaining about my `"version"` line:

```
  [Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]                             
  A repository of type "package" contains an invalid package definition: Inva  
  lid package information:                                                     
  version : invalid value (d4e5bc34008e8c187c302eb4e94200ee4a208c63): Invalid  
   version string "d4e5bc34008e8c187c302eb4e94200ee4a208c63"                   
  Invalid package definition:                                                  
  {"name":"library\/hybridauth","version":"d4e5bc34008e8c187c302eb4e94200ee4a  
  208c63","type":"drupal-library","dist":{"url":"https:\/\/github.com\/hybrid  
  auth\/hybridauth.git","type":"git"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location you're defining it at is wrong. When [defining your own packages](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2), the `version` tag is used to target **branches** or **tags**. If you want specify a commit-level project requirement, do it in `require` object where you're specifying your requirement in the  `dev-${BRANCH}#${COMMIT_HASH}` format.

In `repositories`:

```
{
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "hybridauth/hybridauth",
    "version": "master",
    "type": "drupal-library",
    "source": {
      "url": "https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth",
      "type": "git",
      "reference": "master"
    }
  }
```

In `require`:

```
"hybridauth/hybridauth": "dev-master#38f0735",
```